# Install a Library without cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode, charts

I am trying to install this [library](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) without using Pods. In their [git](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/issues/1474), they explain that it's possible to do it by dragging the `.xcodeproj` file on the user project:

> Yes you can copy it the classes like before. However it's more
>   comfortable to drag the xcodeproj to the project. It's not recommended
>   to drag the sources themselves, as this will make updating Chrats in
>   your project more difficult.

By dragging the project I get an error When I try to import the module:

> No such module 'Charts'

I also selected `my project -> Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries` and added the `Charts.framework`. That didn't solved the problem.

Comment: Instead of dragging proj just drag the `chart` folder into your project. That should also work.

Comment: The main chart folder, that contains also proj?

Comment: No, there is another source folder inside it which contains all classes

Comment: No, but there is a folder called srouces. However I do not know how to make the classes use swift 4 as I am using siwft 3 and the library 4

Answer (score 0):

I think to use any of the cocoa pods you have to build a header file as maybe the code that you are going to use might be in objective C and you might be using swift.

1. Simply create briding header file with named
   "projectname-bridging-header.h" at root of your project.
2. Now got to build setting of project and in that do below changes:

   Install objective-c compatibility header : YES
3. objective-C briding header : set path of your bridging header like
   "projectname/briding header file name.h"
4. once its done import all your objective c file of pods which u want
   use in swift app.

**Note : if required then set the path as a recursive in the resource headers and Swift compiler search section.**

let me know if any issues :)